# Web8.5 CMS Connection Error: Attempt by security transparent method

Tags: cme, web8.5

I have just installed Web8.5 on a Cloud server with the Domain Controller from a server on premises. I have not been able to connect to the CMS from a local machine on premises and also on the Cloud server itself. I suspect some permission issues or firewall issues, but I was hoping that it will at least work on the server directly with localhost. See the error I am getting below when I attempt to open the CMS on localhost. Has anyone seen this error before? If you have how did you resolve it?

> Attempt by security transparent method 'Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Http.UITraceInfo.TraceStart(System.Web.HttpContextBase)' to access security critical method 'Tridion.Logging.Tracer.GetTracer(System.String, System.String, Int32, System.String, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Nullable`1, System.Nullable`1<System.Guid>, System.Nullable`1)' failed.
>   Assembly 'Tridion.Web.UI.Core, Version=8.5.0.22656, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues was that the Cloud Servers were setup with `medium trust` level.

To fix this, change the trust level for IIS to full trust.
Example of how to do it is on technt below.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831632(v=ws.11).aspx